# Not show the first ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a UIViewController that is painted red inside, this viewController I want to see as the first screen but never starts with the ViewController, what am I doing wrong?

```
UIWindow window;
        [Export("window")]
        public UIWindow Window { get; set; }

        [Export("application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:")]
        public bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            View view = new View();
            UINavigationController navigationMain = new UINavigationController(view);


            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
            window.RootViewController = navigationMain;
            return true;
        }
```

I get this error:

```
 Proyect[4195:115403] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=4195
 Proyect[4195:115403] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Proyect[4195]/0#-1 LF=0
 Proyect[4195:115403] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=4195
 Proyect[4195:115403] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Proyect[4195]/0#-1 LF=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On iOS 13 (and up), the scene delegate takes over some of the roles of
>   the app delegate. Most importantly, the concept of a window is
>   replaced by that of a scene. An app can have more than one scene, and
>   a scene now serves as the backdrop for your app’s User Interfaces and
>   content.

Start form iOS 13,  the [SceneDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate?language=objc) is responsible for setting up the scenes of your app, as well as set up their initial views.

```
[Export ("scene:willConnectToSession:options:")]
public void WillConnect (UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
{
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see UIApplicationDelegate `GetConfiguration` instead).

    UIWindowScene myScene = scene as UIWindowScene;
    Window = new UIWindow(myScene);
    UIViewController viewController = new UIViewController();
    UINavigationController navigationMain = new UINavigationController(viewController );
    Window.RootViewController = navigationMain;
    Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
}
```

For more information, you can read [this article](https://learnappmaking.com/scene-delegate-app-delegate-xcode-11-ios-13/) and [watch the official video of Optimizing App Launch in iOS13](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/423/)

Comment: @mikkylekyle What do you mean the login view is hidden? You should use your own LoginView instead of UIViewController in my code.

Comment: Sorry, I does not get your point. I mean you can use your own ViewController as the first ViewController of your project. Not a View but a ViewController.

Comment: @mikkylekyle Yes, I think so.

Comment: also help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149219/contrait-when-rotate-screen please