# Constraints when rotate screen

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have this configuration with constraints, i can see the fields but when i rotate the screen, all is miss, i do not see anything

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {

        field1.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 10, 100, 20);
        field2.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 50, 100, 20);
        field1.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;  
        field2.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false; 

    View.AddConstraints(new[] {
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field1, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, -200),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field1, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 40),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field1, NSLayoutAttribute.Top , NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, View.Bounds.Size.Height/2),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field1, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0)
        });

        View.AddConstraints(new[] {
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field2, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, field1, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field2, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, field1, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 1, 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field2, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, field1, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 10),
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field2, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0)
        });
}
```

but when I rotate the screen of my cellphone this configuration does not work, the textfield I do not see, how can I fix this wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show us what you want to achieve? Where is the textfield?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i edited my question see please !!!

Comment: Does your problem resolved?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i need your help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187327/how-alignement-two-elements-with-contraints

Comment: Ok, I will check it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field1, NSLayoutAttribute.Top , NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, View.Bounds.Size.Height/2),
```

Once you set the `View.Bounds.Size.Height/2`, it's a constant and won't update after you rotate the screen.

So the easilest solution is change it to    :

```
NSLayoutConstraint.Create(field1, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1, -20),
```

Or you can update the constraints after rotating.